# TortoiseSVN: How to update multiple directory in a single window

Tags: tortoisesvn

I want to create a command file that will update my SVN. I have two different path.

I have a code below that will update two unique directory. Is there a way to do it in a single line of code?

```
@echo off

cd C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\
start TortoiseProc.exe /command:update /path:"C:\Files\SVN Repository\_Testing" /closeonend:0
start TortoiseProc.exe /command:update /path:"C:\Files\SVN Repository\_UAT" /closeonend:0
```

I want it to look like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1sfC3.jpg

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-automation.html):

> Since some of the commands can take a list of target paths (e.g. committing several specific files) the `/path` parameter can take several paths, separated by a `*` character.

One of the examples at the end of the page demonstrates this:

> ```
> TortoiseProc.exe /command:commit
>                  /path:"c:\svn_wc\file1.txt*c:\svn_wc\file2.txt"
>                  /logmsg:"test log message" /closeonend:0
> ```

So you should put both paths together separated by a `*`. Try:

```
start TortoiseProc.exe /command:update /path:"C:\Files\SVN Repository\_Testing*C:\Files\SVN Repository\_UAT" /closeonend:0
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick and easy answer. This is what I am looking for.

Comment: flawless answer @Ic.